# Dynamic queryable parameter to database interface

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Ill keep the question short, as i suspect the answer may be a short no..
I would like to be able to pass a query into an entity framework function, to enable dynamic runtime querying through the ui to the database?
I imagined this to be like passing an IQueryable into a method, but exactly how i would go about this, i am a little unsure at the moment. Am i thinking about this the wrong way? Perhaps querying in the business layer, not semi-directly to the database?

Comment: Let me see if I got it clear, what you want is to let the user add parameters to the query, ex, add some itens on the screen and let the user selects which of them would enter the query. Or what you want is to let the user write some expression and the translate that to the database?

Comment: I worked this out a few weeks ago. I ended up using `VBCodeProvider` to compile my query string (surrounded by the boilerplate code) at run-time, in memory, then executing it against the EF model. FYI, I went with VB because it's LINQ expressions are a little more powerful than C#'s.

Comment: @bateloche from your two options, the first is probably better in terms of data security, but the expression method was more what i was originally thinking of. 
Thinking about it, the options on screen could boil down to an expression interface method under the hood, just not be exposed for security?

Comment: @NickStrupat Have you got some code for this? it seems quite interesting! Also, it may be a bit of a side-question, but in what way is VB linq more powerful?

Comment: @ChrisWatts VB.NET LINQ query syntax has support for aggreate/sum, take/while, skip/while, and distinct right inside the query. In C#, you have to use LINQ method syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, I'm providing the two options.

1. Based on a set of options given to the user.
   Use a TreeExpression to build you expression dynamically, somthing like the example above (this example is indeed too simple, but you can have an idea).

   ```
   ParameterExpression numParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "num");
   ConstantExpression five = Expression.Constant(5, typeof(int));
   BinaryExpression numLessThanFive = Expression.LessThan(numParam, five);
   Expression<Func<int, bool>> lambda1 = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, bool>>(numLessThanFive, new ParameterExpression[] { numParam });
   ```

This link will give you some more info on the subject: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx

2. For letting the user type some expression and converting it to a query, search for Antlr http://www.antlr.org/, or some tool like this, padronize the expression syntax you want to implement and go for the 1º solution to build the expression.

Comment: Wow, thats ridiculous, and very flexible, I had a look into the antlr stuff and i think that might be just a little to complex for the application, let alone security holes. At least if i provide the basic information for creating a query and use part 1 of your answer, then its a bit more controllable as to the content and areas that can be queried!

Answer (score 0):

My example code is below. You'll need to install the following packages...

```
install-package entityframework
install-package newtonsoft.json
```

**Be aware that this code is susceptible to injection by inserting valid VB.NET code to escape the query.**

I compiled the code into `30742268.exe`, which you can see is added as a reference for the `IContext` interface, etc.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using Model;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace _30742268 {
    class Program {
        const String queryWrapperCode = @"
            Imports System.Linq
            Imports System.Data.Entity
            Imports Model

            Public Class DynamicQuery
                Implements IDynamicQuery
                Public Function Run(data As IContext) As IQueryable Implements IDynamicQuery.Run
                    Return {0}
                End Function
            End Class
        ";
        static void Main(String[] args) {
            using (var provider = new VBCodeProvider()) {
                var parameters = new CompilerParameters();

                parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.dll");
                parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("EntityFramework.dll");
                parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("30742268.exe");
                parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;

                Console.WriteLine("Enter LINQ queries, 'demo' for an example, 'exit' to stop:");
                for (;;) {
                    try {
                        var dynamicQueryString = Console.ReadLine();
                        if (dynamicQueryString == "exit")
                            return;
                        if (dynamicQueryString == "demo")
                            Console.WriteLine(dynamicQueryString = "from person in data.People where person.Name.Length = 4");

                        var results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, String.Format(queryWrapperCode, dynamicQueryString));
                        if (results.Errors.HasErrors) {
                            var sb = new StringBuilder();
                            foreach (CompilerError error in results.Errors) {
                                sb.AppendLine(String.Format("Error ({0}): {1}", error.ErrorNumber, error.ErrorText));
                            }
                            throw new InvalidOperationException(sb.ToString());
                        }

                        var assembly = results.CompiledAssembly;
                        var assemblyType = assembly.GetTypes().Single(x => typeof (IDynamicQuery).IsAssignableFrom(x));
                        var constructorInfo = assemblyType.GetConstructor(new Type[] {});
                        var dynamicQuery = (IDynamicQuery) constructorInfo.Invoke(null);

                        using (var context = new Context()) {
                            dynamic result = dynamicQuery.Run(context);
                            foreach (var person in result)
                                Console.WriteLine(person);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception exception) {
                        Console.WriteLine(exception);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

namespace Model {
    public interface IDynamicQuery {
        IQueryable Run(IContext context);
    }

    public abstract class Entity {
        public override String ToString() {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore });
        }
    }

    public class Person : Entity {
        public Int64 Id { get; protected set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public virtual Home Home { get; set; }
    }

    public class Home : Entity {
        public Int64 Id { get; protected set; }
        public String Address { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Person> Inhabitants { get; set; } 
    }

    public interface IContext {
        IQueryable<Person> People { get; set; }
        IQueryable<Home> Homes { get; set; }
    }

    public class Context : DbContext, IContext {
        public virtual DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Home> Homes { get; set; }

        IQueryable<Person> IContext.People {
            get { return People; }
            set { People = (DbSet<Person>)value; }
        }

        IQueryable<Home> IContext.Homes {
            get { return Homes; }
            set { Homes = (DbSet<Home>)value; }
        }

        public Context() {
            Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            Database.SetInitializer(new ContextInitializer());
        }
    }
    class ContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Context> {
        protected override void Seed(Context context) {
            var fakeSt = new Home {Address = "123 Fake St."};
            var alabamaRd = new Home {Address = "1337 Alabama Rd."};
            var hitchhikersLn = new Home {Address = "42 Hitchhiker's Ln."};
            foreach (var home in new[] {fakeSt, alabamaRd, hitchhikersLn})
                context.Homes.Add(home);

            context.People.Add(new Person { Home = fakeSt       , Name = "Nick" });
            context.People.Add(new Person { Home = fakeSt       , Name = "Paul" });
            context.People.Add(new Person { Home = fakeSt       , Name = "John" });
            context.People.Add(new Person { Home = fakeSt       , Name = "Henry" });
            context.People.Add(new Person { Home = alabamaRd    , Name = "Douglas" });
            context.People.Add(new Person { Home = alabamaRd    , Name = "Peter" });
            context.People.Add(new Person { Home = alabamaRd    , Name = "Joshua" });
            context.People.Add(new Person { Home = hitchhikersLn, Name = "Anne" });
            context.People.Add(new Person { Home = hitchhikersLn, Name = "Boris" });
            context.People.Add(new Person { Home = hitchhikersLn, Name = "Nicholes" });
            context.People.Add(new Person { Home = hitchhikersLn, Name = "Betty" });
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this, the ability to explicitly confine this to a certain database area, while also allowing free string querying is very useful!
edit > just found out i cant choose both as answers, despite being both as useful as each other and providing unique information! darnit!